# Elasticsearch suggest returns Unknown SuggestionBuilder

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch to reach auto suggest for Chinese documents, but I get error unknown suggestionbuilder.

Here is the code I build my elasticsearch index.

```py
url = "http://localhost:9200/autocomplete"


payload = {
  "mappings": {
    "values" : {
      "properties" : {
        "value" : { "type" : "text" },
        "value_suggest" : {
          "type" :     "completion",
          "analyzer" :  "ik_max_word",
          # "search_analyzer" : "ik_max_word",
          # "preserve_position_increments": False,
          # "preserve_separators": False
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Here is the search code.

```py
payload = {
"suggest": {
"autocomplete": {
    "prefix": str(search_term),
    "completion": {
    "field": "value_suggest"
    }
}
}
}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
# print(payload)

url="http://192.168.4.36:9200/autocomplete/_suggest?pretty"
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

terminal response:

```
POST request called
糖
suggest {'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'unknown_named_object_exception', 'reason': 'Unknown SuggestionBuilder [autocomplete]', 'line': 1, 'col': 30}], 'type': 'unknown_named_object_exception', 'reason': 'Unknown SuggestionBuilder [autocomplete]', 'line': 1, 'col': 30}, 'status': 400}
192.168.16.225 - - [06/May/2020 10:13:17] "POST /autocomplete HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Wei, are you getting this error for only Chinese suggestions? is that working on English?

Comment: @DARK_C0D3R in Chinese and other language.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: On ES 7.7, the first of your queries produces a 400: `{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [values : {properties={value_suggest={analyzer=ik_max_word, type=completion}, value={type=text}}}]"}}`, given that your headers are content-type: application/json.